# Pulling Docker Images Increase GCP Cost/Decreases Performance/Storage Immensely

Tags: docker, google-cloud-platform, docker-compose

My main problem started first when I tried to deploy my docker image to gcp and received the error **No Space Left On Device**. After looking a while I found out that I had to delete the /var/lib/docker and pull the image again.

```
sudo umount /var/lib/docker/
    sudo systemctl stop docker
   sudo umount /var/lib/docker/
   sudo rm -rf /var/lib/docker/
    sudo systemctl restart  docker
    docker pull myImage
   docker run --rm -v /var/run/docker.sock:/var/run/docker.sock -v "$PWD:/rootfs/$PWD" -w="/rootfs/$PWD" docker/compose:1.26.0 up -d
```

When I want to get rid of the previous images/containers etc I run `docker system prune -a` but nothing seems to get pruned. And whenever I want to deploy another image same problem repeats.

As a result of this I have two terrible problems which become even worse for the last 3 days.

1. Server become incredibly slow I am getting 502 Bad Gateaway (nginx, I am assuming server stopped responding). I am getting this message which asks me to increase the performance
   **This instance has had high memory utilization recently. Consider switching to the machine type: custom (1 vCPU, 6.25 GB memory)**
2. Server costs increased a lot. First whenever I deployed a new image I was charged with 20-30 euros of GCP Storage egress between NA and EU which kept increasing. And for the last 3 days I am still charged for this even when I don't deploy anything. To give a comparison my estimated server total costs for a month increased from 150 euros to 925 euros.

I also tried to look at the inode usage before but I couldn't find the problem.

My docker images in total are around 400 MB. So it shouldn't make the disk full. My machine type is  custom (1 vCPU, 4.75 GB memory)** and it has a 10 GB standard persistent disk

How can I fix these issues? I am especially concerned with the first question, but I think the answer to first question should help with second question as well.

Note: My VM is in Germany hence the cost for pulling the image from gcr.io (It pulls it from NA. I don't know how to pull it from Germany)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

When using docker inside GCP, i would consider using the GCR (Google Container Registry).

Your 502, probably causes a container restarting duo to health checks forever. a problem which. So an infinitive restart loop. With an always pull policy.

Are you running docker on a VM? or are you using GKE(Google Kubernetes Engine)

Anyway, if you decide to use GCR, you never pay for image pulls...
As long as your VM/GKE lives in the samen zone/region

You can choose to pull the images from a specific location using, another host:

eu.gcr.io instead of gcr.io

See: https://cloud.google.com/container-registry/docs/pushing-and-pulling

You probably also have to build it new on de eu.gcr.io

Google Container Registry is store on a Cloud Storage Bucket.
You can just wipe the bucket, to be sure it's gone.

Check the storage browser from cloud console:
https://console.cloud.google.com/storage/browser?project=PROJECT_ID_HERE

The bucket should look like this:
.artifacts.<project_id>.appspot.com

Please make sure to browse it first, as removing the bucket will wipe all your artifacts.

Comment: Yes I forgot to mention it, I will edit the question for that. I pull it from GCR but my machine is in Germany and it pulls the images from US. I don't know how to pull the images from Germany. I am using a VM but how can I find out / delete probably the remainders of docker images that wastes all the resources

Comment: I modified the answer, where to find your stored images. and how to choose a region for pulling and building

Comment: Thanks a lot, both of the issues have been resolved and server is faster again so I am accepting the answer. To avoid this in future, should I periodically delete the artifacts manually? And are those artifacts were the reason of all that wasted resource?

Comment: In fact you should make sure your docker daemon / swarm or kubernetes cluster is accessing the the registery with an appropriate service account.

Then you can could control which machine is allowed to pull from which registry.

And do not relay on public GCR's.. as this is an big risk... if someone knows your image name / url, they could cause you a huge bill, without much effort.